# Как вытащить координаты из файла JSON? C#

Tags: c#, json, api

Пишу приложение на C#,но я новичок. Нужно, чтобы по введенному тексту определило координаты нас. пункта и отобразило на карте. Решил воспользоваться API Maptiler,ответ на запрос возвращает мне в формате JSON, а там большое количество, пока не нужных мне данных. Сейчас мне нужны только координаты, например, под ключом "center", там массив из 2 элементов.

```
JObject obj1 = JObject.Parse(json1);
             lat1 = (double)obj1["center"][0]["lat"];
             lng1 = (double)obj1["center"][0]["lon"];
```

Мои попытки примерно такие, и еще несколько вариаций подобного... Естественно все безуспешные. json1 всегда получает значение null, записал динамический объект в строку - тоже null...

Это мой запрос:

```
string url1 = "https://api.maptiler.com/geocoding/" + location1 + ".json?&key=" + apiKey;
```

При вводе его в браузер вручную, данные выдает.

Comment: "как распарсить json, который я не покажу"? Кстати, Newtonsoft.Json устарел.